# Why a div with higher z-index is not visible (covered)?

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/61cgeqs0/) an inner green div is covered by a middle blue div, at least in Chrome, despite that it has a higher z-index. Why is it so and how to make it visible over the blue div? The green div must be inside an outer yellow div. From the top:

```
1. #inner
2. #middle
3. #outer
```

Comment: you will need to move the `#middle` `div` inside `#outer` for the `z-index` to work http://jsfiddle.net/61cgeqs0/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could achieve that but you will need to move the `#middle` `div` inside `#outer` for the `z-index` to work

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
}
#outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  background: yellow;
}
#inner {
  width: 240px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 30px;
  background: green;
  z-index: 2;
}
#middle {
  width: 280px;
  height: 140px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: blue;
  top: -16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
  <div id="middle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why it is so? Why the outer div cannot have a z-index and contain a div with another z-index?

Comment: `z-index` only works with individual elements not with parent child elements eg if there are 3 individual elements you can set z-index but if you have a parent child it will not allow the child to come above parent